# Gauß and mean curvature

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces

I was wondering whether the Gauß, mean curvature and shape operator of a surface actually depend on the chosen parametrization?

Under a reparametrization of $f: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S \subset  \mathbb{R}^3$ I understand a diffeomorphism $\Phi : M \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Omega$  such that our surface is given by $f \circ \Phi$.

Intuitively, I would say that neither of them is conserved under reparametrization, as every surface is locally an embedding and therefore all of them vanish, am I correct about this?

The shape operator is given by $L = -DN Df^{-1},$ where $N$ is the Gauß map.

Comment: It does depend on the embedding to induce a metric. But the reparametrization does not change the curvature.

Comment: could you explain why? - Especially the Theorema Egregrium made me feel that the curvature properties will change

Comment: It might help if you're specific about what you mean by "reparameterization". Also, to even talk about the mean curvature and shape operator, you need an embedding of your surface $S$ into some other Riemannian manifold $M$. (Are you thinking of $S$ as being embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3?$) However, it's at the very least false that the Gaussian curvature, mean curvature, and shape operator of a surface all vanish. (They wouldn't be very interesting if they did!)

Comment: @mollyerin Done....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$In the usual sense of "depend",[*] no, the Gauss curvature, mean curvature, and shape operator of a (locally oriented) regular surface in $\Reals^{3}$ do not depend on parametrization; that's what's meant by saying these are "geometric" data. :)

Depending on your definition of the shape operator (e.g., O'Neill's: If $U$ is a continuous unit normal field on $M$ in a neighborhood of $p$ and $\nabla$ denotes the covariant derivative, then $S_{p}(v) = -\nabla_{v}(U)$ for each tangent vector $v$ to $M$ at $p$), it's more or less clear the shape operator doesn't depend on the parametrization (i.e., depends only on the set of points in $M$ and the ambient Euclidean geometry of space).

The Gauss and mean curvatures are the determinant and trace of the shape operator, so they also do not depend on parametrization.

[*] The coordinate representations *do* generally change under reparametrization, as would the representation of any non-constant function.

Comment: I never heard of this definition of a shape operator and I don't understand why it should not depend on the parametrization, sorry.

Comment: The value $S_{p}(v)$ is the (signed) curvature at $p$ of the plane section of $M$ by the plane spanned by $v$ and the unit normal $U$, i.e., the reciprocal radius (up to sign) of the osculating circle to this plane section. The Wikipedia pages for the [second fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) and [principal curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature) may be helpful.

Comment: do you think it is possible to show this invariance also by the definition of the shape operator that I now added to my question?

Comment: (Just noticed I've used "$M$" to denote the surface. I'd avoid "$S$" for the surface, lest we use a single letter to denote a surface, its shape operator, and possibly also the unit sphere.) I don't understand your notation "$L = -DNDf^{-1}$": If $f$ is a parametrization of $M$, and if $N:M \to S^{2}$ is the Gauss map, then $DN$ and $Df^{-1}$ aren't composable (regardless of whether "$Df^{-1}$" means $(Df)^{-1}$ or $D(f^{-1})$...? In case it helps, O'Neill's definition of the shape operator is (essentially) $-DN$.

Comment: $f: \Omega \rightarrow M$ and $N: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$

Comment: Ah...! What you call "the Gauss map" I'd call "the Gauss map in local coordinates". To me, $N \circ f^{-1}:M \to S^{2}$ is "the Gauss map". Anyway, does it make sense that $N \circ f^{-1}$ maps a point of $M$ to "the" unit normal at that point, and that $-D(N \circ f^{-1})$ has the stated geometric interpretation/meaning?

Comment: it does yes and it makes also sense that all these things do not depend on the parametrization, but i could not show it

Comment: If you're seeking a computational argument, it may help to notice that $N \circ f^{-1} = (N \circ \Phi) \circ (f \circ \Phi)^{-1}$ for every reparametrization $\Phi$.